# Extracting Values in setdefault set dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am setting a dictionary using setdefault option

```
self.dict = {}
self.dict.setdefault(key, {})
```

I am saving multiple values against the key. After saving some values the dictionary contains:

```
self.dict = {'key1': {2: 1} , 'key2' : {3:4} }
```

How can I extract multiple values of the key in case mentioned below:

```
if key1 in self.dict:
```

value2 = ? (extract value 2 in {2: 1})
value1 = ? (extract value 1 in {2: 1})

Comment: So, to be clear, You want to know what the only key is in a dict?  If so, `next(dct)` will do the trick (or in your case, `next(self.dict['key1'])`

Comment: @mgilson, `next(iter(dct))` that is

Comment: @shx2 -- Yep, that's what I meant :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dict.items()` is the list of pairs your dict contains.

To get the first pair, do:

```
dct = self.dict['key1']
value1, value2 = dct.items()[0]
```